# Ubuntu from a stick

Tags: usb

Is it posible to install Ubuntu on to a USB stick so it is self contained on that USB stick?

Like I'm not trying to install from a USB stick, but onto a USB stick INSTEAD of a hard drive so it is a portable Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator)

Answer (score 0):

A Ubuntu Live image on a USB drive works quite well.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization .. loads from ram, and should save your stuff, too.

Comment: Live Mode was not asked for. An installation instance was.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a usb stick of at least 8GB to put the Ubuntu installation on

Create a live usb or burn Ubuntu on a dvd.
Next connect the usb stick you want to install Ubuntu on.
Now reboot into the live system. (Choose boot from usb or dvd in bios)
In the live system choose install Ubuntu.
When you arrive at "Installation type" choose "Something else"
You will now see a partitioning tool which sums up all the connected drives
including the usb stick you want to install Ubuntu on. The first drive will be called
/dev/sda, the second /dev/sdb and so on. Under the header 
"Divice for boot loader installation:" you will be able to see the size of
the drive you select, which should give you the information you need to choose 
the usb stick you would like your Ubuntu on. Make sure you choose the right
drive or you might loose an existing installation or data. Also make sure you choose 
the usb stick you want to have Ubuntu on as "Device for bootloader installation"
or you won't be able to boot the Ubuntu usb stick.
Now you need to create a partition table on the usb stick.
Create an ext4 partition with mountpoint / and a swap partition.
After this step choose install now and the installation will guide itself.